# How to bind the selected value of a DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

Data binding is all about declarative code, right?  So I specify what I want with attributes, and the framework takes care of the rest.  Unless I'm mistaken and data binding relates to S&M, right?

So, why does the DropDownList control only provide binding fields for its data source, i.e. its list source, and not for its actual data field. i.e. how the heck to I bind the selected value my name DropDownList to the Name field in my Person record?  Is this a gross oversight on Microsoft's part, or on mine?

What is the point of two way data binding if I still have to manually set and read the selected value?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You might want to do something like the code below.
You can not set the "SelectedValue" declaratively, but by saying
"SelectedValue=<%#  [code here] %> you are effectively causing the value to be set when the control is data bound.

```
<asp:DropDownList
                ID="DropDownInfoSource"
                runat="server"
                DataSourceID="_employeeDataSource"
                DataTextField="EmployeeName"
                DataValueField="EmployeeID"
                SelectedValue='<%# Bind("EmployeeID") %>'
                />
```

Comment: Thanks, I was a bit quick off the mark: I just looked in Intellisense for a Value attribute, and none showed, so I asked without looking further.  We need an embarrassed emoticon in comments.

Comment: I get, in .NET 4, an error stating: "A call to Bind must be assigned to a property of a control inside a template" even though the control is inside an ItemTemplate of a GridView.  Changing Bind to Eval worked for me.

Comment: @Andrew - Mine is inside an edit template field, and I'm using asp.NET 4.0. I tried using EVAL instead of Bind, but it still didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: The idea is don't but the Bind expression in double quotes "" out it in single quotes ''

Comment: @AndrewShepherd: Apologies for dragging this one back up from the depths of time, but do you know if there is any specific reason why the setting doesn't appar in intellisense?

Comment: Alternatively, you can also use `SelectedIndex="0"` to set the first item selected.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will really help you, but did you tried to setup the "SelectedValue" on Code behind?

Example:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    DropDownInfoSource.SelectedValue = "1" ' your value, here
End Sub
```

Comment: Eventually the selected value will be change for been selected one selection or another.... so it is necesary to every time it is loaded to change to the real value of it, not to the initial value.....

Answer (score -1):

There is a field where you define the datasource, the datatextfield (what shows up in the list) and the datavaluefield.

Example (I have a datatable with a column "EmployeeID" and a column "EmployeeName"):

```
dropdownlist1.datasource = DT
dropdownlist1.datatextfield = "EmployeeName"
dropdownlist1.datavaluefield = "EmployeeID"
dropdownlist1.databind()
```

Comment: If you read my question you'd see I know about those.  I wanted to know how to bind the selected value to another data source, as I asked.

Comment: It doesnt matter if you know about that. If your question should be beneficial to others maybe it should include a variation of solutions.