# how to show list of CustomerId in dropdown list

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

i want to create Customer diary on the base of customerID that present in customer table[image: see the pic].

In customerID field i want dropdown list having list of CustomerId's that are present in database

How can i do that ? can someone help me please

Comment: You need to go to the MVC site and work through some tutorials to understand the basics of using MCV

Answer (score 1):

```
var _objAllCustomerIds = null; 
using (AdventureWorksEntities context = new AdventureWorksEntities())    
{

_objAllCustomerIds = context.MyCustomers.Select(customer =>     customer.Id).ToList();

}
```

> //where AdventureWorksEntities is your DBcontent containing all your entities
>   //MyCustomers is the entities representation of your customer table

Comment: hi   [HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Diary diary)
{

   if (!cd.Customers.Any(c => c.CustomerID == diary.CustomerID))
   {
    ModelState.AddModelError("CustomerID", "Customer not found");

    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        cd.Diaries.Add(diary);
        cd.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
    }

    return PartialView("_CreateDiary");
}
this is my code can you edit this one please

Comment: m very new to mvc dont knw how to do that, can you please edit my code

Comment: The code that renders this page is the Controller that displays the partial (the partial view is _CreateDiary ) view. you can find that controller by putting a debugger on this controller and following it to that controller. It is inside that controller that we will add the required code.

Comment: hey sorry to say can you edit my controller code, m confused here

Comment: Check out this link..

https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

go through it and when you finish you will have a better idea of what to do...if you have any question after reading it ask me and I will explain

Comment: but they are using hard code data for dropdown. isnt it?

Comment: That was used initially just to explain. They later used the database and entity framework dbcontext ...keep reading you will get it.

Comment: m confused you know, got stucked

Answer (score 0):

if this is in your .aspx file

then in your .aspx.cs file (assuming you're using code behind) you'd get the list of customer IDs and then bind that list to this dropdown.

Does this answer from another question help?
[How to bind the selected value of a DropDownList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604186/how-to-bind-the-selected-value-of-a-dropdownlist)

Comment: m using mvc4, and i just need list of customerid that are present in customer table because my dairy from is based on CustomerID

Comment: @kirandeep yes, what happens when you do this? <asp:DropDownList
                ID="DropDownInfoSource"
                runat="server"
                DataSourceID="_employeeDataSource"
                DataTextField="EmployeeName"
                DataValueField="EmployeeID"
                SelectedValue='<%# Bind("EmployeeID") %>'
                />