# How to get data from SQL Server database and display it in dropdownlist + asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a dropdownlist which contains Yes and No. By default the value is Yes. I want to extract the value from a SQL Server database but at the same time it also can be edited either want to remain yes or change to No.

Currently my source code only show one value.

Example: first time I choose Yes and it will go to database, when search again, the value show Yes. But I cannot choose No. I need to change value to No.

Here is my source code:

```
 strsql = "Select IN_USE FROM FixedAssetMaster_old WHERE ASSET_NUMBER=" & AssetTxt.Text & " AND LOC_DEPT=" & DeptTxt.Text & " AND UNIT_NO=" & UnitNoTxt.Text & " And (DATEPART(MM, UPDATE_DATE) = " & nowMonth & ") And (DATEPART(yyyy, UPDATE_DATE) =" & nowYear & ") ;"
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(strsql, Conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    da.Fill(ds)
    da.Dispose()
    DDLInUse.DataSource = ds
    DDLInUse.DataTextField = "IN_USE"
    DDLInUse.DataValueField = "IN_USE"
    DDLInUse.DataBind()
    'DDLInUse.Items.Insert(0, "")
    ds.Dispose()
```

Comment: You're doing the binding wrong.  The `DataSource` needs to contain ALL the possible values.  It's the `SelectedValue` that is supposed to represent the value selected from that list. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604186/how-to-bind-the-selected-value-of-a-dropdownlist).

Comment: Set AppendDataBoundItems=true for your DropDownList

Comment: @GaganDeep i try that one but it come out what in the database and also value in dropdownlist.it means come out something like Yes No No

Comment: @jmcilhinney what you mean by DataSource need to contain ALL possible value?

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't come here to explain the meanings of common words.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i just try your solution but come out this error "Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control"

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);  
            string com = "Select * from UserDetail";  
            SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(com, con);  
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
            adpt.Fill(dt);  
            DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;  
            DropDownList1.DataBind();  
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Name";  
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ID";  
            DropDownList1.DataBind();  
        }
```

Comment: That looks like C# and the tag and code in OP is vb.net.